# Chartjs custom colors not displaying when dataset is changed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, signalr

I am trying to create 2 distinct line charts which display 2 different datasets. With this, I want to display 2 different colors for each chart.

```
<div style="display: block" *ngIf='signalRService.data'>
    <canvas baseChart id="data1"
            [datasets]="signalRService.data1"
            [labels]="chartLabels"
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [legend]="chartLegend"
            [chartType]="chartType"
            [colors]="colors"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div style="display: block" *ngIf='signalRService.data'>
    <canvas baseChart id="data2"
            [datasets]="signalRService.data2"
            [labels]="chartLabels"
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [legend]="chartLegend"
            [chartType]="chartType"
            [colors]="colors"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
  </div>
```

At the moment, I have signalRService.dataX which is containing specific data from the larger signalRService.data. When I separate the data into 2 variables to assign them to different charts, the colors and color settings stop working and revert to their defaults (Light gray with a fill). I also have them both on the same componenent.

Fixes I have tried:
I have tried to use the [data] property instead of [datasets] which hasn't worked, as I can't read signalRService.data[0] because it's undefined.

I tried to create 2 separate arrays for colors, which hasn't worked either.

I have looked into, but haven't really figured out how I can use `[datasets]="signalRService.data"` and then hide a different dataset for each chart.

The best solution would be if I was able to adjust colors and maintain the rest of the code or to be able to hide a dataset on each graph (I will have 3, so I'd want to hide 2 of 3 datasets). However, I'm open to any ideas, even what I might have "tried" but done incorrectly.

Below is my app.component.ts file in case it's necessary.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SignalRService } from './services/signal-r.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';
import * as pluginCrosshair from 'chartjs-plugin-crosshair';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public chartOptions: (ChartOptions) = {
    responsive: true,
    spanGaps: false,
    animation: {
      duration: 0
    },
    scales: {
      // We use this empty structure as a placeholder for dynamic theming.
      xAxes: [{}],
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-0',
          position: 'left',
          ticks: {
            max : 30,
            min: -30
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    
    plugins: {
      tooltips: {
        mode: "interpolate",
        intersect: false,
      },
      crosshair: {
        line: {
          color: '#F66',  // crosshair line color
          width: 2,        // crosshair line width
          value: '0'
        },
        sync: {
          enabled: false,            // enable trace line syncing with other charts
          //group: 1,                 // chart group
          suppressTooltips: false   // suppress tooltips when showing a synced tracer
        },
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    }
  };
  public chartType: string = 'line';
  public chartLegend: boolean = true;
  public chartLabels: Label[] = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17',
  '18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40',
  '41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59'];
  public chartPlugins = [pluginCrosshair];
  public colors: any[] = [{ // grey
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)',
    fill: false
  }, 
  {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,100,0,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,100,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)',
    fill: false
  }];

  constructor(public signalRService: SignalRService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signalRService.startConnection();
    this.signalRService.addTransferChartDataListener();
    this.signalRService.addBroadcastChartDataListener();
    this.startHttpRequest();
  }

  private startHttpRequest = () => {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/api/chart')
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  }

  public chartClicked = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    this.signalRService.broadcastChartData();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out. If I replace the reference in the html to the colors array with just the information itself like this

```
[colors]=" 
            [{
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,100,0,0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,100,1)',
              pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
              pointBorderColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)',
              fill: false
            }]"
```

and I also change the data1 and data2 variables to slices (using Arrays.slice) of the original super dataset, it works.